# How to show tool tip when cursor is on ListView cell?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listview

I have `listview` object, and several columns in it. One of the columns does not fit all text info, and the text has been cutted. I need to implement something like this: when user move mouse cursor to this column's cell, all the text is shown. Is it possible to do that ?
Now i have:

```
 protected ListViewItem GetItem(ListView listView, Point mousePosition)
    {
       Point localPoint = listView.PointToClient(mousePosition);
       return listView.GetItemAt(localPoint.X, localPoint.Y);
    }

    private void myListView_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
       ListViewItem item = GetItem(myListView, Cursor.Position); 
       // or should I use e.Location instead of  Cursor.Position?

       item.ToolTipText = "my info"//Now I need to show "my info" on the cell 
       //that user move cursor on
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the old ways to show decent tooltip with lists is to hide a label and make it visible at the desired location, with the desired text for the desired duration. Benefit of this could be multi-line, multi-color tip.

So it works like this:

- the label sits on the listview or form and it is invisible.
- on mouse move you get item data using mouse X and Y. Position, 
  size and show your label filled with data.
- label itself can have a timer, which will start when label 
  is visible and make it invisible in 5 seconds, for example.

I remember doing just that this year. Although my "tooltip" was done over the listbox.
Replace label with a textbox and suddenly you can make your data in the cell editable :o)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
ListViewItem iListView = new ListViewItem("add");
iListView.ToolTipText = "Add Expanded";
myListView.Items.Add(iListView);
```

Do this by setting the ShowItemToolTips property of ListView to true

Comment: I don't need to add new items